# What is the difference between a countermeasure and a control?

Tags: security, terminology, owasp

While reading the OWASP site, I stumbled upon pages

[www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:Countermeasure](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:Countermeasure)

and

[www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:Control](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:Control).

My question is simple: what's the difference between the two?

I'm sure I could see it if there was more information, but right now they both seem to state that they are something that are used to detect, deter, or deny attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is apparent from the supplied links, that at least OWASP considers them to be synonyms.

"Category:Control

This category is a parent category used to track categories of controls (or countermeasure, security mechanisms)."